# Failed to import package with error: Couldn't decompress package? Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, error-handling, missing-data

I am new to Unity and coding itself, I of course was following a tutorial by our Lord and Savior in coding Brackeys. After a few videos, I wanted to take a break so I saved the project, then I tried opening it up again and this error popped up "Failed to import package with error: Couldn't decompress package". Maybe I could of saved it wrong which I doubt.

I tried updating Unity as I was following the tutorial in a earlier build, which completely removed the error, but did not fix the issue of my data of the game missing. I have seen that other people have the same problem, but for different reasons.

If this is truly my mistake, I will just remake everything, it was not a big loss. I just need to know how to not make the same mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I wasn't able to restore my data, but the reason for the corruption was because I was using an older Unity version.